# Angular: How to refresh a div inside component on assets file modification

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, setinterval

I have an external JSON file stored in `assets` folder of the angular app. This config is used to show an image in a component based on the expiration date provided in JSON. I've developed the logic to show the image by fetching data from the file.

## **Problem:**

After deploying the prod build in server, if I change the content in the JSON (inside `assets`), the view automatically doesn't refresh. So I created a `setInterval` function to call the API after every N seconds. This works somewhat perfectly The issue that appears here is on first load sometimes the `setInterval` doesn't get triggered or sometimes if I change the value in JSON, the interval function doesn't work. This issue doesn't happen in DEV server as because when changing data in assets the angular server refreshes as a whole.

Code I wrote for interval:

```js
time: NodeJS.Timer;

ngOnInit() { this.getPassDetails() }

ngOnDestroy() { this.time = null }

private getPassDetails() {
  this.time = setInterval(() => this._ymcaform.fetchPassDetails().subscribe(response => this.CONFIG = response), 1000);
}
```

What's the problem here? Is there any other way to refresh UI when JSON inside assets changes?

Comment: what is `time: NodeJS.Timer` ? Why are you using `NodeJs.Timer`. The browser environment is different from node environment

Answer (score 0):

Okay try doing this one thing in your component. Add **changeDetection** in your component.ts file.

Like this:

```
@Component({
  // other data
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

See how this works. This will detect the input changes and will trigger change detection.

Comment: do I need to inject OnChanges hook for this?

Comment: No you dont need to do that.

Comment: I modified but that didn't work. I noticed the JSON was getting cached, so changing the headers to `no-cache` solved the problem

Comment: Oh yes even that is a valid thing to check.